# Excel 2013 VBA: Error: byref agrument type mismatch Sub has NO Arguments

Tags: excel-2013, vba7

I have some VB code that processes 1 excel workbook and generates others.

When I run it I am getting:

> byref agrument type mismatch

This stops at the entry to my subroutine, which reads:

```
Sub AddRowToICWorksheet() 'It stops here
    Dim nextrow As Integer
    Dim TempICName As String
        
    'Cut off the leading
```

As you can see, I have NO arguments.

My calling routine is:

```
Private Sub checkICNamesInDataList()
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim ICFound As Range
    Dim ICFoundRow As Integer
    Dim ICName As String
    Dim oldICName As String
    Dim missingICNames As String

    For row = 2 To WorkSheetRows
...
        AddRowToICWorksheet
    Next row
    If missingICNames <> "" Then
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

No arguments declared. None passed. So, how can this be a mismatch?

Office 2013 (64bit). I have the same issue with 32bit.

I have no add-ons enabled. I have uninstalled and reinstalled excel. My system has 64 GB of memory and the Excel spreadsheets total to 130 KB of file size. The Excel version is the latest for 2013 and there are no updates available.

I am confused by why no arguments can result in an argument type mismatch.

The complete subroutines are:

Comment: can you post entire definition of both subs

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the request for the full definitions, I did not want to post all that code here. So, I went back and made the subroutine empty. No args. It worked. Then I began adding back lines 1 at a time. The error was being called out due to an undeclared variable. The high lighted line was the subroutine definition. I checked my debug settings and I do have require variable declaration set/enabled.

So, this is my error but I was taken off on a tangent because of the error message.

I should have simplified and debugged further. Thank you for the help.

Comment: *I do have require variable declaration set/enabled* - hopefully that's changed now, yeah? [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com) inspections can help you locate all undeclared variables, among other things.